# MVC Add User and Edit User in same View

Tags: c#, html, model-view-controller

I have a situation where i am trying to create a user administration view in MVC and inside the same view i want to be able to edit and add new user but i am not able to figure out what am i doing wrong and how to go about to display the User list and User Edit/Create form on the same view.

Currently I have two partial views, one for displaying the user list in a table and the other for displaying the Create/Edit form. Everything works fine except the issue is that when i click on the Edit button in the users list i return the partial view where the edit/create form is but the result is that i get only that view displayed and i want the list also to be displayed even when i click on the Edit button.

I tried to return the Index view (view where both partial views are displayed correctly) when I click on the Edit button but how would I go about passing it the user Id since that view is already returning as a List of users.

Here is the AccountController code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using NEASports.Models;

namespace NEASports.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        OurDBContext db = new OurDBContext();
        // GET: Account
        public ActionResult Index()
        {



                return View(db.userAccount.ToList());            



        }

        // GET Akcije za registraciju
        public ActionResult Register(int id)
        {

            return View("_UserEditPartial", db.userAccount.Find(id));

        }

        //Post Akcija za registraciju
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Register(UserAccount account)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (account.Id <= 0)
                {

                    db.userAccount.Add(account);

                    ModelState.Clear();
                    ViewBag.Message = account.FirstName + " " + account.LastName + " uspješno registrovan.";
                }
                else
                {
                    db.Entry(account).State = EntityState.Modified;

                }
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");


            }

            return View(account);
        }



        // Akcije za Logon
        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(UserAccount user)
        {


                    var usr = db.userAccount.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Username == user.Username && u.Password == user.Password);
                    if (usr != null)
                    {
                        Session["Id"] = usr.Id.ToString();
                        Session["Username"] = usr.Username.ToString();
                        Session["FirstName"] = usr.FirstName.ToString();
                        Session["LastName"] = usr.LastName.ToString();
                        return RedirectToAction("Index");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Pogrešan Username ili Password");
                    }


            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult LoggedIn()
        {
            if (Session["Id"] != null)
            {
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Index View code:

```
@model IEnumerable<NEASports.Models.UserAccount>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Message = "Lista korisnika";

}

@{
    NEASports.Models.UserAccount user = new NEASports.Models.UserAccount();
}

<div>

    @{ 
        Html.RenderPartial("_UserEditPartial", user);
    }


</div>

<div>
    @{
        Html.RenderPartial("_UserListPartial");
    }
</div>
```

This is the UserList Partial View code:

```
@model IEnumerable<NEASports.Models.UserAccount>

<div class="box box-info">

    <div class="box-header with-border">
        <h3 class="box-title">@ViewBag.Message</h3>
        <div class="box-tools pull-right">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse" data-toggle="tooltip"
                    title="Collapse">
                <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Remove">
                <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-body">


        <div>
            <table id="table1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)</th>
                        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)</th>
                        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)</th>
                        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Username)</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)</td>
                            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Username)</td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Register", new { id = item.Id }) |
                                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
                                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)</th>
                        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)</th>
                        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)</th>
                        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Username)</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>

        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.box-body -->
    <div class="box-footer">
        Lista svih korisnika
    </div>
    <!-- /.box-footer-->
</div>
```

And the Edit user Partial View code:

```
@model NEASports.Models.UserAccount    

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
    ViewBag.Message = "Administracija Korisnika";
}

<div class="box box-danger">
    <div class="box-header with-border">
        <h3 class="box-title">@ViewBag.Message</h3>
        <div class="box-tools pull-right">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse" data-toggle="tooltip"
                    title="Collapse">
                <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Remove">
                <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-body">

        @using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account"))
        {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <form role="form">
            <div class="form-horizontal">


                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                @if (ViewBag.Message != null)
            {

            }
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Unesite Ime" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Unesite Prezime" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Unesite Email" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Username, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-sm-4 control-label" })
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Username, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Unesite Username" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Username, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-sm-4 control-label" })
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Unesite Password" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-sm-4 control-label" })
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Ponovite Password" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-12">
                                <input type="submit" value="Sačuvaj" class="btn btn-success" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        }

    </div>


    <!-- /.box-body -->
    <div class="box-footer">
        Otvaranje novih ili ažuriranje postojećih korisnika
    </div>
    <!-- /.box-footer-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*@Html.ActionLink* will redirect your page, which you want to avoid.
So to keep your content and update only a specific section, you have to use **Ajax call**.

1. First replace the *@Html.ActionLink* with a non-hyperlink element such as div, section, ...

```html
<span class="EditUser" data-id="@item.Id">edit</span>
```

2. Add an ID to the div where you want to display the partial view as following:

```html
<div id="EditUserSection">
    @{ 
        Html.RenderPartial("_UserEditPartial", user);
    }
</div>
```

3. And finally add JavaScript file such as the below (jQuery included)

```js
$(document).on('click', '.EditUser', function () {

    var id = $(this).data('id');

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Account/Register?id=" + id,
        cache: false,
        success: function (partialView) {

            $('#EditUserSection').html(partialView);
        },
        error: function (x, y, z) {

            // Handle Exception
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

On click of Edit button, you can do one of two things:

**1- Without reloading the page (using javascript)**

(a) Grab the respective values for a user from the `List`

(b) Populate `EditUser` form with those values, without redirecting the page.

**2- With reloading the page (without javascript)**

(a) Route/return to `Index` view

(b) In your controller, (before loading `Index` view) check if `Index` is being called from Edit press.

(c) If it is, then grab `$_POST` data and pass it to `EditUser` view

(d) In `EditUser` view, check if any data for a user is received/set. If it is, then populate the form accordingly.